# JSX TypeScript definitions override for custom framework's components?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, jsx, typescript-typings

I'm working on an opensource JS framework and I want to use JSX with typescript for it's components. But I have an issue with type definitions for JSX

TS expects:

```
<Header title="Hello World" />
```

to be (for any react-like framework):

```
function Header(props: { title: string }) : JSXElement
```

While in this framework the actual type is based on Observables ([RxJS](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/class/Observable)):

```
function Header(props: Observable<{ title: string }>) : JSXElement | Observable<JSXElement>
```

E.g. a simple `h1` header component:

```
function Header(props$) { // take in a stream of updates
  return props$.pipe(     // return a stream of JSX updates
    map(props => <h1>{ props.title }</h1>)
  );
}
```

So, components receive an Observable of properties and return a static JSX element or a stream of JSX elements.

**UPD to clarify:** The framework already works as I described, the typings is the issue. Observables are handled in the engine **runtime**, not in the transformation phase, so JSX transformation to `createElement` is fine. I just need to adjust typings for TSX, something like:

```
// current:
createElement<P>(fn : (props: P) => JSXElement, props: P, ...children: JSXElement[])

// should be:
createElement<P>(fn : (props: Observable<P>) => JSXElement, props: P, ...children: JSXElement[])
```

I see that one can partially customize [JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) but I haven't found a way to override that. I've tried to override `JSX.Element` and `JSX.ElementType` w/o any visible change to typings outcome.

**Is it even possible to do this override?**

**What types/interfaces should I override?**

Thanks!

*~~I'm not linking the repo not to be suspected in advertising~~*

*UPD: For details, you can find the framework here: http://recks.gitbook.io/*

Comment: I'm almost certain, that you won't receive your Observable inside the component. That it will be lost in React.createElement. The only way I see to pass an Observable is as a value. Either a single prop or through a Context.

Comment: Hey, @Thomas! It's a custom framework and it provides it's own `createElement` and the engine to handle Observables (in and out). So it already works as I described above, I just want to add proper typings to improve dev experience

Comment: @arslan2012, afaik, JSX is a special sub-syntax in TS and TSC is fully capable of doing the transformation. Also, the `createElement(fn, props, ...children)` transformation is fine for me, the Observable part is handled in the engine -- so I don't need a custom transformation -- just typings. Basically I need to tell TS that `createElement<P>(fn : (props: P) => any, props: P, ...children: any[])` is now `createElement<P>(fn : (props: Observable<P>) => any, props: P, ...children: any[])`. Sorry for not making it clear, will update Q to better reflect that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `LibraryManagedAttributes` can do the override I was looking for.

[Preact uses it](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/blob/e968a5a4000dfa9bec7e8d7b26543b23def6d29d/src/jsx.d.ts#L22-L26) to add `defaultProps` to component types:

> ```
> type LibraryManagedAttributes<Component, Props> = Component extends {
>   defaultProps: infer Defaults;
> }
>   ? Defaultize<Props, Defaults>
>   : Props;
> ```

So I similarly overrode it with:

```
type LibraryManagedAttributes<Component, Props> =
    Props extends Observable<infer O>
    ? O
    : EmptyProps;

interface EmptyProps {}
```

*`EmptyProps` is a hack to ensure components w/o proper type won't accept attributes.*

It seem to work (at least, affect the types):

[image: code example]

**NOTE:** as shown in this screenshot, you'll need to override built-in TS definitions for JSX via a namespace `global.[LIB_NS].JSX` or directly via `global.JSX`. For more details, see the section at the very bottom of official docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#factory-functions

**Big thanks** goes to [Josep M Sobrepere](https://twitter.com/Joseptec) for giving me a hint on preact's `LibraryManagedAttributes` override!

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding and customizing  `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts` and `node_modules/@babel/types/lib/index.d.ts` I was able to set `React.FC` to the type `{foo: 'bar'}` and also update the `JSXElement` to have the same type, and then write a component that returns that object & renders it without producing a type error. I am testing by modifying the typings in a React project. I didn't test with your library, but I think the key is to not load the React typings and instead load your own typings. The fact the typings are effectively global is the larger issue, consumers of your project may need separate tsconfig files to use both libs in the same project with this approach.

Comment: Hey, Josh! Thanks for taking your time on this! As far as I understand it, the issue is rather not **how** to override, but **what** to override. It seems like TS is already bundled w/ some TSX definitions (before React adds it's d.ts), though TS allows us to override its definitions via a namespace `global.[LIB_NS].JSX`  or directly via `global.JSX` (see the screenshot in my sibling answer, and docs at the very bottom of https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#factory-functions). Not sure but hope including this override would be sufficient. Let me know if I'm missing something